# How does resources work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, resources

This is my currently working routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get 'static_pages/help'
    get 'static_pages/test', as: "can_do_this"
    get 'static_pages/home', to: "static_pages#home", as: "home"
    root 'application#hello'

end
```

However, if I add the line:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :static_pages #added this line
    get 'static_pages/help'
    get 'static_pages/test', as: "can_do_this"
    get 'static_pages/home', to: "static_pages#home", as: "home"
    root 'application#hello'

end
```

Then my code breaks and any content I have on my pages does not show. Can someone explain to me what this line does and how to use it?

Comment: Please read the documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

resources :static_pages will create these 7 routes for you

```
GET        /static_pages                  static_pages#index
GET        /static_pages/new              static_pages#new
POST       /static_pages                  static_pages#create
GET        /static_pages/:id              static_pages#show
GET        /static_pages/:id/edit         static_pages#edit
PATCH/PUT  /static_pages/:id              static_pages#update   
DELETE     /static_pages/:id              static_pages#destroy
```

While you need to have Controller representing static_pages as well and the required views.

Hope this helps..

Let me know if you still have any queries..

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in your `routes.rb`

```
resources :static_pages
```

will generate following restful routes

```
    static_pages GET    /static_pages(.:format)           static_pages#index
                 POST   /static_pages(.:format)           static_pages#create
 new_static_page GET    /static_pages/new(.:format)       static_pages#new
edit_static_page GET    /static_pages/:id/edit(.:format)  static_pages#edit
     static_page GET    /static_pages/:id(.:format)       static_pages#show
                 PATCH  /static_pages/:id(.:format)       static_pages#update
                 PUT    /static_pages/:id(.:format)       static_pages#update
                 DELETE /static_pages/:id(.:format)       static_pages#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, `resources :static_pages` creates several routes. Among which there is this one:

```
static_page GET    /static_pages/:id(.:format)       static_pages#show
```

So when you request, for example, http://localhost:3000/static_pages/help, it is this route that matches this url. It invokes `StaticPagesController#show` action with params `{'id' => "help"}`. Your custom `help` action is not considered, because matching route is already found.

A couple of possible ways here:

1. Serve your static pages from `show` action (by id) and remove your custom routes.
2. Place `resources :static_pages` after your custom routes, so that custom ones match first.